# Inputting php the right way....GET php

Tags: php

Hello I was wondering if I am doing this PHP correct. I am almost 100% is right and should be working. Here is the code:

```
if($url == '/user/view.html.php?user_id='. $_GET['user_id'].') {
```

I was wondering if the $_GET part was correct. Is the PHP above correct?

Comment: what the complete code for that line ?

Comment: @Butterfruit say wut??

Comment: What does that possibly have to do with SQL injection?? @Butterfruit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the second tick. You're done concatenating after your `$_GET` statement it looks like.

```
if($url == '/user/view.html.php?user_id='. $_GET['user_id']) {
```

Comment: Yea.... that right up does seem to work thanks!!